# How to calculate different between times in different hours?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the time-in and time-out of the employees. I can calculate the total hours out of it. The allow late mins are 30 per month. After crossing 30 mins threshold every minute will be calculated late.

The problem is that our office is divided into 4 times.

```
9:00 am to 11:00 am
11:15 am to 11:30 am  (Break)
01:00 pm to 02:00 pm  (Break)
02:00 pm to 05:00 pm  
05:15 pm to 06:00 pm  (Break)
```

Now if you come late after 09:00 am, it will be calculated late, if you come after 11:30 again late, same for 02:00 pm and 05:15 pm.

How would I calculate something like and wold contribute to late mins > 30.

For this I have 5 columns TimeIN, TimeOUT , TotalHours, AllowedLateMins adn employeeID.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TimeIN, , TimeOUT) AS TotalHours
```

But for the different breaks etc I can not calculate.

Update: For now I m doing this.

```
Select InTime, OutTime, DATEDIFF(Minute, InTime, OutTime) as Diff, Sum(DATEDIFF(Minute, InTime, OutTime)) 
Over(Order by e_id rows unbounded preceding) as Total
from [UNIS 22Dec].[dbo].[Tb_Compile_Attendance]
where e_id= 1001
```

Updte:

till now I hve done this.

```
Select top(1) TotalTimeTobeSpent  from MinutesConfig

Declare  @TimetoBeSpent int
Set @TimetoBeSpent = (Select top(1) TotalTimeTobeSpent from MinutesConfig)

Select top(1) TotalTimeTobeSpent  from MinutesConfig

Declare  @FlexiMins int
Set @FlexiMins = (Select top(1) FlexiMins from MinutesConfig)

Select InTime, OutTime, DATEDIFF(Minute, InTime, OutTime) as Diff, 
SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, InTime, OutTime))  Over() TotalHrs
from [UNIS 22Dec].[dbo].[Tb_Compile_Attendance]

Declare @RemFlxMins int

/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 [id] 'S.No'
      ,[e_date] 'Date'
      ,[e_id]   'Employee ID'
      ,[e_name] 'EmployeeName'
      ,[InTime] 
      ,[OutTime]
      ,[Indate]
      ,[outdate],
        DATEDIFF(Minute, Case when CAST(InTime AS time) < '08:30' then '08:30' else InTime end,  Case when CAST(OutTime AS Time) > '18:00' then '18:00' when (CAST(OutTime AS Time) > '10:00' AND CAST(OutTime AS Time) < '10:15') then '10:00' else OutTime end) as 'Difference (Mins)', 
        @TimetoBeSpent 'TimeToBeSpent (Mins)',
        SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, Case when CAST(InTime AS time) < '08:30' then '08:30' else InTime end, Case when CAST(OutTime AS Time) > '18:00' then '18:00' when (CAST(OutTime AS Time) > '10:00' AND CAST(OutTime AS Time) < '10:15') then '10:00' else OutTime end))  Over() 'ActualTimeSpent (Mins)',
        (@TimetoBeSpent - SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, Case when CAST(InTime AS time) < '08:30' then '08:30' else InTime end,Case when CAST(OutTime AS Time) > '18:00' then '18:00' when (CAST(OutTime AS Time) > '10:00' AND CAST(OutTime AS Time) < '10:15') then '10:00' else OutTime end)) Over()) 'Late (Mins)',
        (@FlexiMins - (@TimetoBeSpent - SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, Case when CAST(InTime AS time) < '08:30' then '08:30' else InTime end,Case when CAST(OutTime AS Time) > '18:00' then '18:00' when (CAST(OutTime AS Time) > '10:00' AND CAST(OutTime AS Time) < '10:15') then '10:00' else OutTime end)) Over())) 'RemainingFlexiMins',
         @FlexiMins as AllowedFlexiMins
  FROM [Tb_Compile_Attendance]
  where InTime is not null and outtime is not null
```

Output:

```
S.No    Date    Employee ID InTime  OutTime Indate  outdate Difference (Mins)   TimeToBeSpent (Mins)    ActualTimeSpent (Mins)  Late (Mins) RemainingFlexiMins  AllowedFlexiMins
145 20190721    1001    08:30   10:01   20190721    20190721    90  480 476 4   86  90
164 20190721    1001    10:16   13:00   20190721    20190721    164 480 476 4   86  90
165 20190721    1001    14:03   16:15   20190721    20190721    132 480 476 4   86  90
166 20190721    1001    16:30   18:01   20190721    20190721    90  480 476 4   86  90
```

Comment: The time periods are not contiguous. What if someone comes between 11:00 and 11:15?

Comment: that doesn't matter if comes between. :) only after

Comment: Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it and your desired results.

Comment: If an employee came at 11:45 to work today. How late is he? How much minutes?

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко. 3 hrs and 15 mins.

Comment: You May be over complicating the solution. Why not just calculate the Time difference between all the in/outs Between your target window to derive the hours?Also, what is the End time? What if an employee exceeds x hours but compensates those hours by staying late?

Comment: @GouriShankarAechoor: end time is 6 pm nd doesnt matter if he stay after 6. it won't be compensated

Answer (score 1):

I created a table with work periods (the periods when a worker **MUST** be at work, without breaks). Here's my version of periods, change these data as you need:

```
create table dbo.WorkTimePeriods
    (
        FromTime    time            not null,
        TillTime        time            not null,

        constraint pk_dbo_worktimeperiods primary key (FromTime, TillTime),
    )
go

insert  dbo.WorkTimePeriods
    (FromTime,TillTime)
values  (cast('09:00:00 am' as time),cast('11:00:00 am' as time)),
        (cast('11:30:00 am' as time),cast('01:00:00 pm' as time)),
        (cast('02:00:00 pm' as time),cast('06:00:00 pm' as time))
```

So, the resulting query looks like this (with my sample data for Employees visiting):

```
;with cte as
    (
        select  *
        from    (
                    values  (1, cast('20190101 08:59:00' as datetime), cast('20190101 11:00:53' as datetime)),  --  this guy is normal one
                            (1, cast('20190101 11:29:50' as datetime), cast('20190101 13:05:00' as datetime)),
                            (1, cast('20190101 13:58:31' as datetime), cast('20190101 18:05:10' as datetime)),

                            (2, cast('20190101 08:59:00' as datetime), cast('20190101 18:00:53' as datetime)),  --  this guy works without breaks - workaholic!

                            (3, cast('20190101 09:09:11' as datetime), cast('20190101 12:59:20' as datetime)),  --  this guy was late and went after the afternoon - lazy one!

                            (4, cast('20190101 09:00:55' as datetime), cast('20190101 11:02:30' as datetime)),  --  this guy is a normal one as well, but he is a bit late sometimes
                            (4, cast('20190101 11:28:22' as datetime), cast('20190101 13:05:10' as datetime)),
                            (4, cast('20190101 13:55:09' as datetime), cast('20190101 18:01:12' as datetime))
                ) as EmplWT (EmployeeId, InTime, OutTime)
    ),
    cte2 as
    (
        select  cast('20190101' as date)    as  CalendarDate
    )

select  v1.EmployeeId,
        v1.CalendarDate,
        sum(v1.PastDueTimeInSec/60.0)   as  PastDueTimeInMin,
        sum((v1.WorkTimeInSec-v1.PastDueTimeInSec) / 60.0)  as  WorkTimeInMin
from    (
            select  v3.EmployeeId,
                    t2.CalendarDate,
                    case when v4.EmployeeId is not null then 0
                        when v5.EmployeeId is null then datediff(SECOND, cast(t1.FromTime as datetime), cast(t1.TillTime as datetime))
                        else 
                                case when v5.InTime > cast(t1.FromTime as datetime) + cast(t2.CalendarDate as datetime) then datediff(SECOND, cast(t1.FromTime as datetime) + cast(t2.CalendarDate as datetime), v5.InTime) else 0 end +
                                case when v5.OutTime < cast(t1.TillTime as datetime) + cast(t2.CalendarDate as datetime) then datediff(SECOND, v5.InTime, cast(t1.TillTime as datetime) + cast(t2.CalendarDate as datetime)) else 0 end
                    end             as  PastDueTimeInSec,
                    datediff(SECOND,cast(t1.FromTime as datetime), cast(t1.TillTime as datetime))   as  WorkTimeInSec
            from    dbo.WorkTimePeriods t1
            cross join cte2 t2
            cross join  (
                            select  EmployeeId
                            from    cte
                            group by EmployeeId
                        ) v3
            left join   (
                            select  t1.EmployeeId,
                                    t1.InTime,
                                    t1.OutTime
                            from    cte t1
                        ) v4 on cast(t1.FromTime as datetime) + cast(t2.CalendarDate as datetime) between v4.InTime and v4.OutTime
                                and cast(t1.TillTime as datetime) + cast(t2.CalendarDate as datetime) between v4.InTime and v4.OutTime
                                and v4.EmployeeId = v3.EmployeeId
            left join   (
                            select  t1.EmployeeId,
                                    t1.InTime,
                                    t1.OutTime
                            from    cte t1
                        ) v5 on v5.InTime between cast(t1.FromTime as datetime) + cast(t2.CalendarDate as datetime) and cast(t1.TillTime as datetime) + cast(t2.CalendarDate as datetime)
                                and v5.EmployeeId = v3.EmployeeId
        ) v1
group by v1.EmployeeId,
        v1.CalendarDate
```

Pay attention, you need to create a Calendar with work dates (in my case it's `CTE2`).

Result:

```
+------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+
| EmployeeId | CalendarDate | PastDueTimeInMin | WorkTimeInMin |
+------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+
|          1 | 01.01.2019   | 0.000000         | 450.000000    |
|          2 | 01.01.2019   | 0.000000         | 450.000000    |
|          3 | 01.01.2019   | 339.183333       | 110.816666    |
|          4 | 01.01.2019   | 0.916666         | 449.083333    |
+------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+
```

I hope this will help you. Good luck!:)

Comment: Wow. This definitely love. But my requires breaks too.